# How to loop through geojson layers on leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet

I have already added geojson features to my leaflet map. I want to be able to loop through those geojson features. WHen I do map.eachLayer(function(layer) {...}) it only shows be the tile layer and none of the geojson that are added.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rather than `map.eachLayer`, you should be using the [`.eachLayer` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-eachlayer) on the L.geoJson itself. For example:

```js
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(myGeoJson).addTo(map);

geoJsonLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.name);
});
```

You can also specify a function to be applied to each feature at the time you create the L.geoJson, using the [`onEachFeature` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-oneachfeature).